# To add double quotes around the strings in a data frame column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame where in column values are having single quotes around them. As per my requirement i had to add double quotes around the string to proceed further.

*For example, If I have a string in a column as **['7hag5thdu4d']**, i need to add double quotes and final string should be like **["'7hag5thdu4d'"]***

Following is my code and output:-

```
import pandas as pd
data = {"id": [1, 9, 8],
        "person": ["['Eswar']", "['john']", "['otis']"],
        "Role": ['{"manager"}', '{"analyst"}', '{"director"}']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.replace("'", '\'"', regex=True)
print(df)
```

| id | person | Role |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ['"Eswar'"] | {"manager"} |
| 9 | ['"john'"] | {"analyst"} |
| 8 | ['"otis'"] | {"director"} |

The problem i'm facing with the output is with left alignment of the characters where they've shifted their places.

Can someone help me in fixing this.........:-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = df.replace('([{\\[])[\'\"]+(.+?)[\'\"]+([}\\]])', '\\1\"\'\\2\'\"\\3', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   id       person            Role
0   1  ["'Eswar'"]   {"'manager'"}
1   9   ["'john'"]   {"'analyst'"}
2   8   ["'otis'"]  {"'director'"}
```

Comment: Are you sure of your result? I think I don't understood the same thing: *add double quotes around* ... *column values are having single quotes* (but English is not my best skills :) lol.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure of them, but this solution seems pretty stable, so I though I'd provide it. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

You aren't accounting for how sometimes you want `'"` and other times you want `"'`. You can do two replaces, one for the beginning and one for the end.

```py
df = df.replace("\['",'["\'',regex=True)
df = df.replace("'\]",'\'"]',regex=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `replace` with a dict of replacement values:

```
df = df.replace({r"\['": '["\'', r"'\]": '\'"]'}, regex=True)
print(df)

# Output:
   id       person          Role
0   1  ["'Eswar'"]   {"manager"}
1   9   ["'john'"]   {"analyst"}
2   8   ["'otis'"]  {"director"}
```

Another way: `df.replace(r"'([^']*)'", """\"'\\1'\"""", regex=True)`